# Check_box in Rails. Data inserted is NULL in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms

How to use `check_box_tag` in rails3 or `f.check_box`

The data is sent to the controller, I see in the post request,
but the entry is not saved in the database.

Please Help me.

```
<%= form_for(@userrole) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Admin %><br />
  <%= f.check_box  "access_type1" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Super_Admin %><br />
  <%= f.check_box   :access_type2%>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Super_Admin %><br />
  <%= f.check_box  :access_type3%>
</div>


<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please post `params` hash and the snippet from the view where you try to use `check_box` or `check_box_tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @davidb, more information is needed, but I have a haunch that you need to make that particular attribute `attr_accessible`.

**RESOURCES**

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Comment: My problem get resolved i used  <%= check_box("model_name", "attribute_name") %>